# Why do I get such code like this

Tags: tensorflow

What does the "compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6" means?
[image]

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not an image. Images aren't searchable (and that font is hard to read).

Comment: (tensorflow) shiwopanghubugousaole:~ lvbaiyang$ python3
Python 3.6.0 (default, Mar  4 2017, 12:32:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:205: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there was an error in creating the binaries for pip, hopefully it will be fixed soon (alternatively python 3.5 seems to work)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14182

Comment: Hamish is right, it is a bug with tensorflow-gpu-1.4.   What i did was:
1.   pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
2.   pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.3
to revert back to 1.3 and it works again.

Comment: Yep, I hope new bug fix could fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your machine is running Python 3.6, but the version of the software you are running was built with an earlier version of Python.